# MVC4 and Responsive Design Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, responsive-design

When used with responsive design templates, my MVC sites are not showing up on mobile the way they do for the demo template. They are always too wide or too narrow. I'm using all the same CSS elements as the purchased templates and not referencing Site.css at all. Is there something built in to MVC here that would be overriding css elements?

Comment: Have a look using Chrome tools on your desktop - if you shrink the browser window so that it's really narrow you should see which style rules are applied to the mobile layout.

Comment: It looks fine when I shrink the browser window but does not appear correctly when actually viewing on a mobile device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebug has a `Responsive Design View`. Try using that tool to help you locate what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it must have been something subtle in my css but seems to be working now. I just need to pour over my css and make sure a single element isn't throwing it off.